# How to create a two-dimensional array, with filling from the center in a spiral? Getting error: Exception in thread...-1 and 9

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, compiler-errors

The movement of the spiral: left, down, right, up; from center [4][4]...
I wrote code, but ran into a couple of errors, namely:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 and 9

Line of code 13: `mx[i][j--] = k;` (and others, like 28...). I just can't understand what I'm doing wrong and why the compiler sees an error here.

```
public class FoLab {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] mx = new int[9][9];
    int i, j, k = 1, n = 1, b;

    for (i=0; i < 9; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            i = 4;
            j = 4;
            if (n % 2 != 0) { //if odd
                for (b = 0; b <= n; b++) {
                    mx[i][j--] = k; //go left
                    k++;
                }
                for (b = 0; b <= n; b++) {
                    mx[i++][j] = k; //go down
                    k++;
                }
                n++; //number of steps after "left + down" is increasing by 1, making it even
            }
            else { //if even
                for (b = 0; b <= n; b++) {
                    mx[i][j++] = k; //go right
                    k++;
                }
                for (b = 0; b <= n; b++) {
                    mx[i--][j] = k; //go up
                    k++;
                }
                n++; //number of steps after "right + up" is increasing, making it odd
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                System.out.printf(" %02d ", mx[i][j]);
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On the first iteration, `j == 0`, `b == 0`, and so the loop will run twice, The first time you will call `mx[i][0]`, and the second time you will call `mx[i][-1]`. Not really sure what this code is supposed to be doing but I'm guessing you either need to start `j` at 1, or only loop while less than `n`

Comment: Why bother having `for` loops for the variables `i` and `j` if you are just going to set them to 4 straight away?

Comment: And, while you are inside the first `for` loop for `i`, you reuse the `i` variable in another `for` loop, thereby trashing any chance for the outer loop to operate correctly.

Comment: Consider using real variable names that tell you what they are used for, rather than `i`, `j`, `k`, `n` and `b` (which mean nothing to someone trying to understand your code).

Comment: @Jason, i, j and k are standart variables for arrays. n - number of steps. b is just fro loop.

Comment: @GBlodgett , but I set i and j to 4 before loops. Is that doesn't matter?

Comment: No, you set them to 4 inside the `for` loops.

Comment: The exception tells you what the problem is - you are trying to access an array item that is outside the bounds of the array - with an index < 0 and/or > 8. Try stepping through your code in a debugger so you can see exactly what is happening to the variables.

Comment: `@Jason ` well, when I just added `i = 4; j = 4;` in all `for` loops complier is just go infinite comp. So, as I understand, I should somehow make the compiler not think that `i` and `j` = 0?
Also, I added comments, so now you can understand what is going on... I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I solved the problem. Here the code:

```
public class Experiment {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] mx = new int[9][9];
    int i, j=1, k = 1, n = 1, b;

    for (i=1; i < 81; i++)
            if (n % 2 != 0) { //if odd
                for (b = 0; b <= n; b++) {
                    mx[i][j--] = k; //left
                    k++;
                }
                for (b = 0; b <= n; b++) {
                    mx[i++][j] = k; //down
                    k++;
                }
                n++; //after "left, down" number of steps increasing by 1, making it even
            }
            else { //if even
                for (b = 0; b <= n; b++) {
                    mx[i][j++] = k; //right
                    k++;
                }
                for (b = 0; b <= n; b++) {
                    mx[i--][j] = k; //up
                    k++;
                }
                n++; //after "right, up" number of steps increasing by 1, making it odd
            }

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            System.out.printf(" %02d ", mx[i][j]);
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

}